# Angular Lifecycle Hook - Async data undefined OnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, lifecycle

I'm trying to access an array within an object that I have loaded from a firestore document, but can't manipulate it in ngOnInit because until it's rendered in the DOM a couple of seconds later, it is undefined.

As a result, I can't set up a new material MatTableDatasource populated with the data from the array I need to access, and when trying to do so, the CLI returns

> Property 'items' does not exist on type Observable

**view=invoice.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { InvoiceService } from '../invoice.service';

import { Invoice } from '../invoiceModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-invoice',
  templateUrl: './view-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class ViewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  userId: string;
  invoiceId: string;
  invoice: Observable<Invoice>;
  items: object[];

  itemsData = new MatTableDataSource();

  tableColumns = [
    'description'
  ]

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private invoiceService: InvoiceService, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userId = this.authService.user.uid;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.invoiceId = params.id;
    })

    this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.invoice = snapshot.data() as Observable<Invoice>;
        this.itemsData = this.invoice.items; <-- Here. "Property items does not exist on 'Observable<Invoice' "...
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer new version

Since you have several observables that need to be called in chain  :

- your API call depends on the result of observable params,
- setting the data field depends on the result of API call
- there seems to be some observables in between

So you should use `flatMap`s that will help you chain the observable calls.

```ts
this.route.params
    .map(params => params.id)
    .do(id => { 
        // you can remove this block completely if you don't have other use of this.invoiceId
        this.invoiceId = id; 
    }) 
    .flatMap(invoiceId => Observable.fromPromise(
        this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(invoiceId).ref.get())))
    .flatMap(snapshot$ => snapshot$) // not completely sure if needed, try with or without this line
    .flatMap(snapshot => snapshot.data() as Observable<Invoice>)
    .subscribe(
        invoice => { 
            this.itemsData.data = invoice.items; 
            console.log('Loaded items : ');
            console.log(invoice.items);
        }, 
        err => {
            console.log('There was an error :');
            console.log(err);
        }
     );
```

Comment: Thanks, just needed changing from this.itemsData to this.itemsData.data in the subscribe method

Comment: @nick.cook ow, yes, maybe, I just adapted the asynchronous Observable part from the assignation in your question. Glad it helped anyway!

Comment: I've just noticed, it's saying in the console that this.invoice.subscribe is not a function. I've tried moving the subscribe from the constructor's document snapshot to the afterViewInit method, but then it returns 'cannot read property subscribe of undefined'

Comment: you have to check if this.invoice is not undefined. You can do like this : 

`if (this.invoice) { this.invoice.subscribe.... }`. That being said, it means that `snapshot.data() as Observable<Invoice>` returned undefined. What exactly is `snapshot.data()` returning ? Do you have a link to some documentation ?

Comment: @nick.cook oh I noticed the probable cause. You have another problem of asynchrony. You are using this.invoiceId while it is undefined (it gets set in another asynchronous call written just before, but not executed yet ). So it can't work as is. You have to wait for invoiceId to be set. Let me some time and I'll write the solution, or maybe someone else will do.

Comment: @nick.cook Hi again, I tried to create a more comprehensive example, also with some basic error handling so you can debug in your console. I don't have your API to test, so not sure about corectness.